# My regex breaks when I "alert" it - because of escaped slashes?

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm currently working on a CKEditor plugin which would add internal links to our CMS. One of the thing their current link plugin does is that it'll parse through a link when it loads the link dialog to figure out what "type" it is.

Since I created the internal type I need to add a regular expression to compare it to and I'm having trouble doing so. I managed to match my expression using [this tool](http://www.regular-expressions.info/javascriptexample.html) but once I use the same expression in the RegExp object definition it doesn't seem to work.

My links look like this:

```
/en/my_folder_5
```

or

```
/fr/my_folder_5
```

I tried the following (which worked in that tool):

```
/(en|fr)/[A-Za-z_^/]+_[0-9]+
```

but all the slashes get escaped when I "alert" the expression (which leads me to believe it might be what's breaking it since I copy pasted the alerted expression and it did not work)

Any help is appreciated :)

Comment: Should `[A-Za-z_^/]+` mean *any alphabetic character and `_` but not `/`*?

Comment: Yeah, I'll remove the last bit as I'm already restricting it to alphabetic characters and the underscore. I don't know what I was thinking :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var regex = /\/(en|fr)\/[A-Za-z_^\/]+_[0-9]+/;
alert(regex.test('/fr/my_folder_5')); // prints true
```